# Why don't two views with shared elevation join and form a seam?

Tags: android, material-design, elevation

I'm building this app that looks like this:
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk2wU.jpg)

Here's a break down of the structure of the app.
[break down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eci9U.jpg)

It is as simple as this:

I need to constantly change the Fragment within the activity. What I want to achieve is to let the LinearLayout in the Fragment look like as if it is part of the app bar (that is, without shadow casted to it).

theoretically if I set the elevation of the LinearLayout equal to the app bar(4dp or 8dp or whatever), they should be able to bridge the step themselves, but no. Even if I set the elevation of the LinearLayout to 20, it still appears to be underneath the app bar.

Is there any way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set android:elevation=0dp (or app:elevation=0dp on support AppBarLayout) and use gradient drawable to draw shadow.